# mbstowcs_s is causing my program to crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is the relevant code:

```
char c;
size_t buffer_size = 0;
wchar_t* wc = (wchar_t*) malloc(buffer_size);

int result = recv(this->m_socket, &c, 1, 0);
mbstowcs_s(&buffer_size, wc, buffer_size, &c, 1); // Something is wrong here
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocated 0 bytes for `wc` and passed that buffer to `mbstowcs_s`.

Comment: Thanks. Changed it to size_t buffer_size = 2;

Comment: Better to use `size_t buffer_size = sizeof(wchar_t);` to express what you mean more clearly

Comment: Even better is to not use malloc for 2 bytes :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. 
the problem is in the last parameter that rappresents "The maximum number of wide characters to store in the wcstr buffer, not including the terminating null, or _TRUNCATE."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx